# Where is site-packages on Windows and Blender 3.0 onwards?

Tags: python, add-on

I am trying to install a package via Blender's python's  `pip` on Windows but first I get:

```
defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
```

and then the add-on that is supposed to find said package doesn't find it anymore.

Where is "normal site-packages" for Blender 3.0 onwards on Windows - so that I can try to make that writeable, and install the package so it can be found? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/266289/42221) answer your question?  It's "PATH_TO_BLENDER_INSTALL\3.X\python\lib\site-packages" replacing X with 0, 1, or 2 as appropriate.  If you installed Blender in the default location it's ""c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.X\3.X\python\lib\site-packages"

Answer (score 1):

What Marty said:

> Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/266289/42221) answer your question? It's "PATH_TO_BLENDER_INSTALL\3.X\python\lib\site-packages" replacing X with 0, 1, or 2 as appropriate. If you installed Blender in the default location it's "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.X\3.X\python\lib\site-packages"

And if you want to be sure you can print `sys.exec_prefix` in the blender python console,look for `lib/site-packages` inside that folder.

```
import sys
print(sys.exec_prefix)
```