Does anyone know how to install Python packages correctly in Blender 4.2 LTS?
I am having an issue where when ever I install a Python package in Blender 4.2 it saves the package to C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages instead of C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\python\lib\site-packages. In the past versions of Blender it would install in the latter and I would be able to use packages inside of Blender scripting.
How can I either make it so that Blender understands where to look for the additionally installed packages or install it in site-packages at the Blender.exe as before?

Hi. Does the 2 year old answer in this post work for you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266287/how-to-install-python-packages-using-the-pip-that-now-comes-with-blender

Hi @curious_1! Thank you for that, that seems to be the solution.

Use the new blender_manifest.toml file to install Python packages.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/extensions/getting_started.html#manifest
# Optional: bundle 3rd party Python modules.
# https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/extensions/python_wheels.html
# wheels = [
#   "./wheels/hexdump-3.3-py3-none-any.whl",
#   "./wheels/jsmin-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl",
# ]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/extensions/python_wheels.html#python-wheels
